# Ways to find out source of a HTTP request?

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, http-headers

What are the various ways through which I can find out the source from which a HTTP request is generated? I know only one, i.e. HTTP referrer field. Is there any other way also?

**EDIT:** Here I am only interested in knowing that whether the request is generated from a machine directly or from some other website. And in case of some other website, then which one? I am not interested in IP level details.

Comment: The one and only thing you can know for sure is the IP address and port of the client that made the request, which is part of the TCP data. All other data is voluntary and may be arbitrarily composed by the client.

Comment: @Kerrek IP can also be forged or masked by the NAT, proxy or something like TOR

Comment: @Eugene: Well, you can at least tell where the request came from. That may or may not be the same place to which the response is ultimately delivered, that's true.

Comment: I have update the question to make it more clear that exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @Kerrek in fact, no, you can't. If I am on your wire, I can forge IP packets and intercept responses, and within those IP packets I can put whatever address I want - it just doesn't matter cause I will intercept responses and not let them go to the real forged IP. There exist plenty of tools to do this.

Comment: @Eugene: You mean if you're on the same switched segment? Perhaps, but in that case I'd argue that your server is no longer on a correctly implemented IP network, non? I don't think you can forge IP packets outside the server's subnet if you don't have control over the server's router. Ultimately, though, if you can derail the network infrastructure itself, then indeed the network protocol data isn't reliable.

Comment: @Kerrek "I'd argue that your server is no longer on a correctly implemented IP network, non?" - not exactly. It can be a spy connected to the wire in the network, so the network is "correctly implemented" but the spy is not :)

Comment: @Eugene: Hmm... so the spy can be the true source of the request, but make it look like the request came from someone else? With ARP spoofing? Wouldn't you at least end up with two different hosts advertising the same IP address?

Comment: @Kerrek who said the spy would advertise the IP address? It would send fake packets to the net, but the lifetime and the route of those packets would be quite short. And in case the server is connected to the world via just one link (as it often happens), then you don't even need to be in the same subnet - you should be hanging on that link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct answer is "Nope​​​​​​​​​​​​. – SLaks♦ Oct 31 at 17:34"

Answer (score 0):

You coud do a [geo lookup of the remote i](http://www.hostip.info/)p...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to get the source from where the request has been made is parsing of request headers. Below is the example on how to retrieve the requested client details.

var agent = Request.Headers.UserAgent;